# Solve/Prove multi variable limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

a) Solve $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{x}$$ 
b) Show that $$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} = 0 $$

For a:

I took $z=xy$ , $ z\rightarrow 0 $ , so $$ \lim_{(y,z)\rightarrow (0,0)}y\frac{\sin z}{z} = 0 $$

For b:
$$ \left | \frac{xy\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} \right | < \left | \frac{xy\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{y^{2}}} \right | < \left | \frac{xy\sin\frac{1}{x}}{y} \right | < \left | x\sin\frac{1}{x} \right | < \left | x \right | $$ 
For $\varepsilon > 0$ I choose $\delta =\varepsilon $.

We have that $$ \left \| (x,y) - (0,0) \right \| = \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} < \delta  $$ so $ \left | x \right | < \delta  $ and then $$ \left | \frac{xy\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} - 0 \right | \leq \varepsilon $$

Am I correct or should I think something else? Any tips/solutions?

Comment: b) is correct, for make it better put $\leq$ instead of $<$. For a) I see clearer writting it like $ |y \frac{\sin (xy)}{xy} |\leq |y|$

Comment: This kind of questions many times raises some light discussions as there seems to exist some disagreement in definitions: some could say the first limit cannot exist as on the path $\;x=0,\,y\to 0\;$  the function isn't even defined.

Comment: @JoseSquare So you think it is better to solve a) by using $\delta$ and  $\varepsilon$ ? Is my way wrong?

Comment: @DonAntonio What's your opinion?

Comment: @Dr.Mathematics I think it all is a matter of definition. I'd tend to accept the fact the limit exists and equals zero even though the function isn't defined completely in any neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: @Dr.Mathematics I really don´t understand your method so I don´t know if it is wrong. If possible I always see the most simple way by bounding the modulus of the function by a function I know the limit and then use the Sandwich Rule (I don´t know if thats the name in English)

Comment: @JoseSquare Oh so you mean that $ 0 \leq \left | \frac{sin(xy)}{x} \right | = \left | y\frac{sin(xy)}{xy} \right | \leq \left | y \right | $ and $ \left | y \right | \rightarrow 0 $ so $ \left | \frac{sin(xy)}{x} \right | \rightarrow 0 $ and $ \frac{sin(xy)}{x}\rightarrow 0 $

Comment: @Dr.Mathematics yeah, thats exactly what I meant, of course the same can be done with $\varepsilon - \delta$ as you did in b)